# Open Word document from Internet Explorer on intranet

Tags: javascript, vba, internet-explorer-8, ms-word

We have an internal website for document management. When you choose to open a document, it run the following script to open the file:

```
<a href="javascript:opendokument('P:\\01\\2-010-01.doc')">012-010-01</a> 

<SCRIPT language=javascript>  
function opendokument(dokument){ 
var objAppl;

try{ 
    objAppl = GetObject("","Word.Application"); 
    objAppl.Documents.open(dokument); 
} 
catch(exception){ 
    objAppl = new ActiveXObject("Word.Application"); 
    objAppl.Visible = true; 
    objAppl.Documents.open(dokument); 
}    
objAppl = null;  
} 
</script>
```

The problem is that the macros in the document is not running correctly now as we move from Windows XP with Office 2003 to Windows 7 with Office 2007 (See [my previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3600272/access-active-document-in-vba-when-document-is-opening))

If I run the script locally on my computer or if I open the documents manually macros work properly. How do I get this to work? Any setting I can do in Word or Internet Explorer, or can I rewrite the script on the site that open documents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try allowing all kind of scripts in IE. I believe there was something about macroses...

Comment: ...in your Trusted Zone, and add your intranet servers into this zone. DO NOT even think of enabling this in the Internet Zone - you would open a gateway for all kinds of malware.

Comment: I add the interanet server to the Local intranet zone. And then I set "Initialize and script ActiveX controls not marked as safe for scripting" to Enabled.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the issues is reated to Security setting of IE.